# Logic behind что meaning "something"

Tags: грамматика

In some cases **что** can be translated as, "something". Why is this? I thought that **что-то** is the equivalent of "something".

Есть чем заняться в этом городе.

У тебя есть что добавить?

если что (случится), напиши мне.

Or is it more like— (very colloquially and just gut feeling translation)
There is a thing to do.
Do you have stuff to add?
If what (stuff), phone me.

Because these phrases are just the opposite of—

нечего— there is nothing

есть что— there is what (stuff, that)

нечем заняться— there's nothing to do.

есть чем заняться— there is wha (a thing)

Comment: As @Баян Купи-ка said in those examples "что" is shortened from "что-нибудь."  Your gut-feeling, as I understand it, also points the same way.  You can replace "что" (similar to your examples) with "some stuff" in a positive statement, or in a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this usage `что` из simply a shorthand of `что-то`

same is true for `какой(-нибудь)`, `чего(-нибудь)`, `кто(-нибудь)`, and their declined forms, in interrogative, conditional and conjunctive sentences

> У тебя нет **какой** газетки почитать?
>
> Не хочешь **чего** перекусить? (Если) захочешь **чего** перекусить, говори.
>
> Если бы мне **кто** сказал/Сказал бы мне **кто**, кем я в итоге стану, ни за что бы не поверил.

i believe `Есть чем/где/когда/кому` don't belong to this category because in this pattern `чем/где/когда/кому` are complete words without the truncated  `-нибудь` part

does this help a beginner? ;^)

the difference between for example `есть кем` and `кем(-то/нибудь) + any verb` can be illustrated by such sentences as

> Мне бы его **кем** заменить = Мне бы его **кем-то** заменить  -
>   *truncated `кем-то/-нибудь`*
>
> Было бы у меня **кем** его заменить - *`кем` doesn't suggest truncated `-то` or `-нибудь` because it's `есть кем` in a form of conjunctive*

OR

> Может ты хотел бы его **кем** заменить? = Может ты хотел бы его
>   **кем-то/-нибудь** заменить?
>
> У тебя есть **кем** его заменить?

Comment: They should belong, as есть чем doesn't make much sense without -то. Yes it's a much better answer.

Comment: quite the opposite, only in this form does it make sense, maybe in a very distant past they had the second part, but in the modern language they don't imply any

Comment: then how does it translate directly? "there is what"

Comment: the negation of `есть чем` is `нечем`, without `-то` or `-нибудь`, as for "there is what" not sure i get the question